# How to suppress warnings and end terminal command after running "webstorm ."

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

The warnings showing / not showing don't really matter but, I'd like to be able to get terminal to complete the command ready for a new command after I run `"webstorm ."` and **WebStorm** starts running. Like how **Visual Studio Code** opens after `"code ."`, finishes in terminal ready for a new command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible. Please vote/follow the related requests on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-193204, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-205244

Comment: That's too bad. Thank you!